# Ussd change to call

Tags: ussd

For some reason my phone can't dial any ussd code more than 5 digits. For example: I could dial *888# but can not dial *5050#. When I dial ussd code more than 5 digits and press the call button it will calling to that ussd code. I do some research but I don't find any questions like mine, but sth like make a call but changing to ussd running, opposite of my problem. My phone is LG X4+ ( yes not a popular phone at all ) i hope someone could help me

Comment: Can you try with any 3rd-party Phone apps (e.g. [Google Phone](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.dialer)?

Comment: Google phone not supported. I try other dialer on the play store but it seem that when making a call it is still using the same system app